# A Key Game of Battleship

Tags: cipher, board-games

What two relevant words are encoded in this game?

*The stuff in the trays doesn't matter too much*

*No special knowledge or programming needed*.

Hint:

> To solve the bottom, combine the top, tray, and theme in a logical manner. The bottom is the cipher, the top barely counts.

[image: Battleship game]

Comment: "Dad! I found that shed key we've been looking for since I was seven!"

Comment: To be honest, when I opened the box, there was a monopoly shoe in that precise location. I figured I better switch it out or people would assume the puzzle was about feet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Top

> It's suspicious that all pins are at the very top. If we map the latin alphabet from left to right and top to bottom, the pins make an anagram of `QWERTY`. Key in the tray + board game theme further makes it clear that we have to do something with the qwerty keyboard layout

Bottom

> To decrypt a coordinate, take the row on a QWERTY keyboard which contains the given letter, and take the `n`th key (left to right) by the given number, starting from the first letter in that row
>  White: `MISS`
>  Red: `SUNK`

Comment: Great job! Although I think I just noticed you have E7 off by a letter,   right?

Comment: @Amoz Ah, right. Fixed it :)